# How to make/create owin authentication middleware in asp.net vnext(MVC 6)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I was implementing owin authentication in login page but I want middle ware of owin authentication in asp.net vnext (MVC6) because I want to redirect into default(Login) page  when user login state as stay long time.The below code is the reference.

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim("UserId",user.Id),
                        new Claim("UserName",user.UserName),
                        new Claim("Roles",user.UserRoles)
                    };
                    var ident = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,user.UserName,user.UserRoles);
                    var authProp = new AuthenticationProperties() {IsPersistent=true,AllowRefresh=true,ExpiresUtc=System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1).ToLocalTime(),RedirectUri="/Account/Login"};
                    IOwinContext owinContext = new OwinContext();
                    owinContext.Authentication.SignIn(authProp, ident);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for Default Login Page if user is not logged In , than you can use  [Authorize] attribute above the controller.

```
namespace Demo.Controllers
{   
 [Authorize]
 public class DemoController : Controller
 {
  // Your Code
 }
}
```

This Should help you..!

Comment: Thanks anil, to share your ideas regarding issue. But I want middleware for user credential which is dynamically catch by any page of mvc6 application and also if user logged-in as long time so I want to redirect default page means logout the page in mvc6.
So this is my problem while developing the project in mvc6.
If you know how to resolve this issue please share your ideas I appreciate your ideas.